# Login with any password in laravel in development mode

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, authentication

We have `auth()` function in laravel and call it like this:

```
auth()->attempt(['email' => 'hello@gmail.com', 'password' => 123456]);
```

I want to set new **provider** for **session guard** and config it at `config/auth.php` too login user with any password in `auth()` function **in development mode** .

But i *can't find a way to do it in my provider file*!

Comment: That seems like bad practice to me. Why not just insert a user into the database and tell your devs to use a specific username/password combination for testing purposes? If not, how would you test a failed login if it always passes? What happens when some dev accidentally forgets a `!` in a comparison and then you move the dev code into production and are unable to catch the error in your tests?

Comment: And Laravel does have it's own `auth` function. Are you saying you've created your own or did you use it?

Comment: You may solve it with a package: https://github.com/imanghafoori1/laravel-anypass or checking it's very simple and brief code. Be aware that this is tipically not within good practices, use at own risk and evaluating upon your own project requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bad idea as you could inadvertently introduce a security risk into your production code. But in the interests of experimentation...

One way would be to overwrite the validation in the default session guard, but I think this is too risky. So I would duplicate your existing production guard and and force it to die if not in development mode. Here's an example assuming you're using the session guard.

---

In `/app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php` register a new guard:

```
    use App\Services\Auth\SillyGuard;
```

...

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Auth::extend('silly', function ($app, $name, array $config) {
        // Return an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard...

        return new SillyGuard(Auth::createUserProvider($config['provider']));
    });
}
```

---

Add it to your `/config/auth.php` - you'll want to overwrite your existing web guard otherwise you'd have to redefine all your routes when you switch from development to production. **You must switch this guard back to your original driver when you go to production mode**

```
'guards' => [
    //others
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'silly',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

---

Copy the file `...src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php` to `app/Services/Auth/SillyGuard.php` and make the following changes:

```
//namespace Illuminate\Auth;
namespace App\Services\Auth;
```

...

```
public function __construct($name,
                            UserProvider $provider,
                            SessionInterface $session,
                            Request $request = null)
{
     if (!\App::environment('local') || !config('app.debug')) {
         die("This guard only works in local debug mode");
     }
     $this->name...
```

...

```
 protected function hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials)
{
    //return ! is_null($user) && $this->provider->validateCredentials($user, $credentials);
    return ! is_null($user);
}
```